# How to retain information using a recursion in Java

Tags: java, recursion

Basically, every time I recurse, I reset the variable "path," but I need to keep that information. Also, I cannot pass it as a parameter. Is there a way to do this?

Here is the code I have now:

```
public List<Person> getDiseaseRouteTo(Person c){

    List<Person> path = new LinkedList<Person>();

    if (this.root == c) {
        path.add(c);
        } else if (this.root != c) {
            path.add(this.root);
            for (DiseaseTree child: this.getChildren()) {
                if (child.contains(c)) {
                    path.add(child.getRoot());
                    return child.getDiseaseRouteTo(c);
                }
            }
        }
        return path;
    }
```

Comment: I think it's fine. any problem in your code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Also, I cannot pass it as a parameter.

You can always create a private helper method where you can pass it:

```
public List<Person> getDiseaseRouteTo(Person c) {
    List<Person> path = new LinkedList<Person>();
    return getDiseaseRouteTo(c, path);
}

private List<Person> getDiseaseRouteTo(Person c, List<Person> path) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a new instance of `LinkedList` every time you invoke the method.

You can create the `path` variable elsewhere, outside the scope of the `getDiseaseRouteTo` method, like janos suggested.